# Make a checkbox and checkbox text disable

Tags: jquery

I have a checkbox which i want to disable with a disable text of checkbox, but i failed to do so. I have the following code:

```
$('input:checkbox[type="checkbox"]').each(function () {
   $(this).attr("disabled", true).attr("readonly", true);
});
```

The above code is not making my checkbox disabled, rather i am able to check and uncheck the checkbox.
The only thing i wanted to do is make the checkbox disabled and if the value of the checkbox which i am loading from backend is checked then it should not affect its state. I also want to disabled the text of the checkbox.

**Please Note** I have generated the Checkbox dynamically and here is the code for it:

```
if (cellvalue == "True") {
    html = "<input type='checkbox' class='checkboxUser' id='checkbox" + rowid + "' checked/>"
}
else {
    html = "<input type='checkbox' class='checkboxUser' id='checkbox" + rowid + "'/>"
}
return html;
```

Comment: share your html sample

Comment: You don't need `:checkbox` and `[type="checkbox"]` together. One of them is sufficient.

Comment: @ArunPJohny can you please let me know which input text html you want, and i am generating the checkbox dynamically...

Comment: try to use .prop() instead of .attr() and see

Comment: like `$('input[type="checkbox"]').attr("disabled", true).attr("readonly", true);`

Comment: @ArunPJohny i tried your suggestion but it does not seems to be working can you please help me in other way..

Comment: @HarshSharma It works for me... http://jsfiddle.net/3LRU9/

Comment: @ArunPJohny do `.attr()` has something like `!important` which we have  the property in css??

Comment: can you share your html sample? because your code is working in my page. I just copy paste your code and its works for me.

Comment: @ArunPJohny please have a look now i have edited my question

Comment: whether you are running the script after the elements are created of before it

Comment: i guess i am running the script after the elements are created

Answer (score 0):

please try the following

```
$('input:checkbox[type="checkbox"]').each(function () {
   $(this).prop("disabled", true);
});
```

Comment: execute the following code after the dynamic generation 

$('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function () {
   $(this).prop("disabled", true);
  });
  
or put it inside ready funcction 

$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function () {
   $(this).prop("disabled", true);
  });
});

Answer (score 0):

You are doing wrong with `$('input:checkbox[type="checkbox"]')`

You should use like this:

`$('input:checkbox')` only

or,

`$('input[type="checkbox"]')` only

---

And use the prop method:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function () {
   $(this).prop("disabled", true);
   $(this).prop("readonly", true);
});
```

---

Also notice the attribute method you are doing wrong here:

`$(this).attr("disabled",true).attr("readonly",true);` //because attr of this.attr is not valid

This should be this:

```
$(this).attr("disabled",true);
$(this).attr("readonly",true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

`prop("disabled", true)` instead `attr(...)`

And

```
$('input[type=checkbox]')
```

As said user Sarath (a little bit corrected):

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function () {
   $(this).prop("disabled", true);
});
```